# Data Binding - Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds : ViewDataBinding and SimpleCalculatorActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

**File name** : SimpleCalculatorActivity.java

**Xml file name** : simple_calculator.xml

I am getting the error message **Data Binding Android - Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds : ViewDataBinding and SimpleCalculatorActivity** in the line `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.simple_calculator);`

I have tried renaming the xml file and rename it back to original name. But did not work for me.

> SimpleCalculatorActivity.java

```
package com.example.borntoflirt.design1;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class SimpleCalculatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SimpleCalculatorActivity binding;

// This simple calculator can only perform operations of either addition, subtraction, multiplication or division.
// So we define four static chars to represent these operations

private static final char ADDITION = '+';
private static final char SUBTRACTION = '-';
private static final char MULTIPLICATION = '*';
private static final char DIVISION = '/';

// Set variable for operations

private double digit;
private double total = Double.NaN;
private String CURRENT_ACTION;

private DecimalFormat decimalFormat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.simple_calculator);
}
}
```

Comment: `private SimpleCalculatorActivity binding;` - binding should be some subclass of `ViewDataBinding`

Comment: How to do that. I am new in Android.

Comment: so read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#binding_data)

Answer (score 0):

The variable of binding should be:

```
SimpleCalculatorBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.simple_calculator);
```

Please follow [this post](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html%20%22%22)

By default, a Binding class will be generated based on the name of the layout file, converting it to Pascal case and suffixing "Binding" to it. The above layout file was main_activity.xml so the generate class was MainActivityBinding.

ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Test"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Make sure your root view of layout is:
`<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: Root view means `activity_main.xml` or `simple_calculator.xml` ??? This might be a silly question. But I am new in Android

Comment: Both my `activity_main.xml` and `simple_calculator.xml` has the same first line code that is `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`>

Comment: i mean simple_calculator.xml

ex:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Test"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>`

Comment: Yes it is there in `simple_calculator.xml`
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp">`

Comment: Yeah, you should wrap it by `<layout></layout>` for data binding

Comment: I changed `Linearlaout` to `layout`. But still the error is there